# Binding listeners of spinners added programmatically to the same function

Tags: android

I have a form that for every filter added a new spinner is created with the same options every time. The functionality when selecting an item from the spinner is the same for every spinner, so I was thinking of how to bind the onItemSelected to the same function for every spinner I create.

My solution is to set the listener as I would usually do and call my function with the arguments of the overridden onItemSelected. Is this correct, or is there another way?

```
        // Fix the width of the spinner so it doesn't get resized when making selections.
        // Get the screen width and subtract the width of the button next to the spinner.
        originalAttributeSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.attributeSelector0);
        originalAttributeSelector.getLayoutParams().width = displayWidth - originalOperatorSelector.getWidth();

        // Create the adapter containing the list of choices for the spinner (as well the style for it)
        // and bind it to the spinner.
        ArrayAdapter<String> attributeSpinnerAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_material_ref, filterAttributes);
        attributeSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        originalAttributeSelector.setAdapter(attributeSpinnerAdapter);

        originalAttributeSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // This is implemented somewhere else in the class
                myOwnSharedOnItemSelected(parent, view, posiiton, id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: So you want to make this code DRY?

Comment: I guess so. Basically on the itel select, based on the selection i will add another view (edit text or radio button or check boxes).